# how to get specific content from lines in python, and then split them?

Tags: python-3.x, split

Suppose I have a logs file like this;

```
{"log": "09-Sept-2023 rate-limit: info: client @ xyz 127.0.0.1#1075", "stream":"stderr", "time": "2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z"}
```

There's a bunch of line entries just like this one in the file, and for each one I just want to print the time "2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z" value for each line. And then once I have those lines, I want split the "." so I only get

```
2023-09-09T04:18:22
```

and ignoring all the miliseconds and Z. I've tried to treat these lines from this file as sepearate dictionaries and tried to access the values of "time," but that isn't working. Because I would try to assign it to a variable and use the .split('.') method. I also can't try to use indexing either, because some lines have fewer content as well. Would appreciate the help here.

Comment: assuming the entire line is actually a string, and time: occurs only once,  you can do something like follows. If ```line='wateverbefore"time": whateverafter'``` and then 
```line.split('"time":')``` should yield a list which you can then index and then further split
```['wateverbefore', ' whateverafter']```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach would actually work. Here's my script using the example that you've provided

```
file = {"log": "09-Sept-2023 rate-limit: info: client @ xyz 127.0.0.1#1075", "stream":"stderr", "time": "2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z"} 
time_variable = file["time"] #fetching the 'time' index of dict 'file'
print(time_variable) #2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z
clean_time = time_variable.split(".")[0] # splitting at the '.' and obtaining the first item
print(clean_time) #2023-09-09T04:18:22
```

Also, if you have a file with multiple lines, you can still follow the same procedure but you'll have to convert the string(which is what readlines will read by default) to a dict. You can use the `eval()` method for that.
So you end up with something like

```
with open("logs.txt","r") as file:
    for log in file.readlines():
        item = eval(log)
        get_time(item)
```

where `get_time()` is a function that does what's in the previous snippet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse the log file using `json` module and then access the `time` key:

```py
import json

log_text = """\
{"log": "09-Sept-2023 rate-limit: info: client @ xyz 127.0.0.1#1075", "stream":"stderr", "time": "2023-09-09T04:18:22.676095594Z"}
"""

log = json.loads(log_text)

t = log.get("time")
if t is not None:
    print(t.split(".")[0])
```

Prints:

```
2023-09-09T04:18:22
```